# Data projection abefore a particular word using Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, projection

I have a coloumn in Postgres which has text in it. I want to search for a particular word in that text and not display anything after that word
Example :If the text is :"I am a very religious user of stack overflow. I always use it for reserach." 
So now I dont want to show anything after the word "always" 
HOW CAN THIS BE DONE?

The Expected O/P should be :"I am a very religious user of stack overflow. I"
The word always is same but may or may not appear in the text.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, 'always.*', '')
```

this will replace everything after (and including) the word `always` with nothing, but won't replace anything if the word is not found.

If you also want to "catch" the same word in upper case or mixed case, just pass a flag to `regexp_replace` to work in a case-insensitive manner

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, 'always.*', '', 'i')
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4307

Comment: Thanks. I also did it using position() and substring